# Replicate swagger-ui's 'urls' behaviour with spec

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui

When using swagger-ui, I am able to provide a 'urls' parameter. This renders one swagger spec per page, with a selector at the top. I would like to do the same thing, but with the 'spec' parameter - i.e. passing swagger jsons instead of urls (that return swagger jsons). I have tried defining 'spec' to be an array of jsons, but it complained that it was not a valid spec.

Is there a way around this? Or, more generally, a way of gluing json swagger specs together in a way that can be rendered by swagger-ui?